# Adding a custom type to codegen.yml

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

My GraphQL schema uses a type called `PointScalar`, which in Typescript would be defined as

```
export type PointScalar = {
  coordinates: [number, number]
}
```

Without any modification, codegen declares PointScalar fields as `Scalars['PointScalar']`, which in turn is `any`.

I can add this to GraphQL:

```
config:
  scalars:
    PointScalar: PointScalar
```

which causes codegen to declare PointScalar as PointScalar, which is great ... but it doesn’t know what a PointScalar is.

How do I get codegen to add an import file or a type statement to the generated Typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
// Name this file as (or anything you prefer): scalar-types.ts
// Place it relative to your codegen-generated types file.

export type PointScalar = {
  coordinates: [number, number]
}
```

Modify your code to point a file instead. #-points a exported type in the file.

```
// file: codegen.yml
schema: "my-graphql-schema.graphql"
generates:
  ./index.ts:
config:
   scalars:
      PointScalar: ./scalar-types#PointScalar
```

Run Codegen and the following import is at the top of your output.

```
import { PointScalar } from './scalar-types';
```