# How to add custom scalars to GraphQL Codegen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, prisma, graphql-codegen

I have a custom scalar in my GraphQL schema and I want my Codegen to generate the correct type fo me.

My schema looks like this:

```
scalar Decimal

type Item {
  price: Decimal!
}
```

and I have added a custom resolver for this scalar which uses [Decimal.js][1].

When I generate my Typescript types from this schema, I want it to recognise `price` as a Decimal type and have the properties that Decimal.js provides.

My codegen config looks like this:

```
schema: "./src/typeDefs/index.ts"
generates:
  ./src/types.d.ts:
    config:
      scalars:
        Decimal: Decimal
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
```

Whilst this generates `Decimal` types, it doesn't recognise it as a type of Decimal.js so it doesn't have any methods that the library exposes.

It generates the following type:

```
export type Scalars = {
  ID: string;
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
  Int: number;
  Float: number;
  Decimal: Decimal; // doesn't have any Decimal.js props
};
```

How can I tell codegen to use Decimal.js to generate the correct type for Decimal?
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165178/adding-a-custom-type-to-codegen-yml?

Answer (score 6):

It's not properly documented for the [typescript plugin](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript), but [mentioned on the blog](https://the-guild.dev/blog/better-type-safety-for-resolvers-with-graphql-codegen#whats-next):

> - You can import your types from a node module package (`User: models-lib#UserType`).
> - You can also map to built-in language types (`DateType: Date`)
> - Aliasing the imports is also possible (`User: ./models#User as MyCustomUserType`)

This [does not work only for `mappers` but also for `scalars`](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/153#issuecomment-776735610). So you're looking for

```yaml
schema: "./src/typeDefs/index.ts"
generates:
  ./src/types.d.ts:
    config:
      scalars:
        Decimal: decimal.js#Decimal
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the import to the graphql.ts file by adding an add in the codegen.yaml:

```yaml
schema: "./src/typeDefs/index.ts"
generates:
  ./src/types.d.ts:
    config:
      scalars:
        Decimal: Decimal
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
      - add:
        content: "import {Decimal} from 'Decimal.js';"
```